# Rails 3 Asset Pipeline - Development Environment Conflict With public/assets Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, development-environment, precompiled

Just to confirm, does running rake assets:precompile amalgamate all js and css files into application.css and application.js files under the public/assets directory? What is the purpose of this file? The reason I ask is because for some reason my development mode is running into a lot of asset loading conflicts with this file, but my production mode runs just fine. It seems that the only way I can get my application to serve assets properly in development environment is to delete these files.

Is there a configuration in my development.rb file that I can setup to prevent my application from relying on this file in development mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
rake assets:precompile:primary RAILS_ENV=production
```

instead of

```
rake assets:precompile
```

should prevent the assets without md5 being added to the public/assets directory - which should make sure the development mode assets are generated dynamically.

Quote

> To stop the creation of the non-hashed filenames in public use:
>
> ```
> rake assets:precompile:primary RAILS_ENV=production
> ```
>
> from:
>   [Why does rails precompile task do non-digest assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007034/why-does-rails-precompile-task-do-non-digest-assets)